# Snowflake Integration Testing Implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a service(Java + Springboot) which uses PostgreSQL database, the service will be migrated to **Snowflake** (cloud-based data-warehousing) so I would like to know what is the best way to implement integration testing

I tried to find a **snowflake docker image** (docker hub) or a **testcontainer** but so far I have not found anything useful, any suggestions?

https://www.testcontainers.org/

https://hub.docker.com/

Comment: Hi Gustavo, Snowflake is a cloud based data platform solution so there isn't any way to run it locally/offline. You will actually need to connect through to your account (or one of your accounts) to run the integration tests (have a look at zero copy cloning which can really help with the "test" data side of things). Suggest reviewing the available connectors which can help with this connectivity: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/conns-drivers.html And I have also seen Docker images for the Snowflake connector for Python which you might be able to wire up.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Donovan mentioned in the comment, Snowflake is a cloud based data platform solution so no Docker or local client is applicable.

For your Java/Springboot application the JDBC driver might be suited for the integration:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-using.html

Answer (score 0):

We maintain several clones of our production database, including allowing developers to Clone the Production database for their own personal dev databases. You can do something like store credentials locally in an environment variable or store them in an AWS account that you can access locally with the AWS CLI then as you push your code to production then have environment variables in Prod that can connect to the Production database.

Our team was very accustomed to local dev databases with Postgres but it was very seamless to great a Cloning strategy for development and it has been extremely easy to maintain and develop, much more so than local dev databases with Postgres.

We also maintain a Clone specially for integration testing with a very similar approach to our dev databases as well.